# gerar id session/cookie seguro php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Estou montando um sistema de login para os meus projetos. Até agora entendi que se usam geralmente sessions, preferencialmente.

O [artigo](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_ID_Properties) diz que uma boa pratica é usar ids de sessões com pelo menos 128 bits de tamanho e com 64 bits de entropia, pra dificultar a adivinhação do id.

Alguém tem alguma dica pra gerar um id com essas características?

Ao que me parece é só dá um randon de 0 ate 340.282.366.920.938.463.463.374.607.431.768.211.456(ou algo próximo)

creio que é mais fácil trabalhar com uma string alfanumérica, certo? (com unns 26 algarismos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não use `mt_rand`, `time`, `rand`, `lcg_value` e nem `uniquid`. Esses recursos PODEM gerar um número único, mas não imprevisível. Alguns chegam a ser patéticos, para prever o tempo usado basta olhar para o relógio, isso não é imprevisível.

---

Utilize algo que seja um CSPRNG, um gerador pseudo-aleatório criptograficamente seguro, você tem isso no PHP 7:

```
random_bytes($Quantidade_De_Bytes);
```

Portanto você pode fazer:

```
$random = random_bytes(32);

$id = unpack('H*', $random)[1];
echo $id
```

O `random_bytes` é um CSPRNG, ele é seguro. Especificar 32 bytes é equivalente a 256 bits.

---

Não precisa de *hashing*? *SHA-3*, *BLAKE2*, *SHA-2*, *SHA-1*, *MD5*, *{coloque o nome aqui}*? Não. As hashes foram feitas para serem indistinguíveis de uma string aleatória. Portanto, se tem uma string verdadeiramente aleatória, ou um pseudo-aleatório seguro, ela já é equivalente a uma hash.

---

O sistema de sessões padrão no PHP 7.1 já usa o `random_bytes`, você pode configurar sua força usando [`session.sid_length`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php) e [`session.sid_bits_per_character`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php).

Comment: Lembrando que a entropia e a previsibilidade de um número aleatório gerado com `random_bytes()` *depende* do algoritmo `CSPRNG` implementado no sistema operacional da máquina. E se não houver um disponível, uma exceção será lançada.

Comment: Se o sistema operacional for inseguro... nada implementado nele será. É bem melhor usar o `/dev/urandom` (ou equivalente) do que usar o Mersenne Twister.

Comment: Na teoria, né?! Muita coisa foi implementada com base na `OpenSSL` e nos deparamos com o [Heartbleed Bug](http://heartbleed.com/) e com as traquinagens da [NSA e seus backdoors criptográficos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_Agency#Software_backdoors), que afetaram até mesmo o *kernel* do Linux.

Comment: Não precisa ir tão longe, o OpenSSL de fato tem vários problemas, [inclusive no PHP](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/80). Se a NSA colocar um backdoor, tanto um Kernel como um Userland vai ficar comprometido. OpenSSL faz um `MD5` _(não sei se é até hoje)_ de `/dev/random`. Se o `/dev/random` for maliciosamente fraco, tudo vai dar ruim. Então, até o próprio `random_bytes()` estaria. Mas, isso é culpa do OS, não da função, o que não é o caso de um `time()` ou `mt_rand()`, ele é fraco por ser fraco. Se você não confia no OS, não tem como acreditar em mais nada.

Comment: Prefiro confiar em um *kernel* cheio de bugs e backdoors do que nos dados e nas moedas haha.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um código capaz de gerar um identificador de 512 bits (128 caracteres em base16 ou hexadecimal), a partir do nome do usuario, da hora local do sistema, do identificador do processo e de um número aleatório:

```
<?php

$user = 'FULANO';
$pid = getmypid();
$now = new DateTime();
$rnd = mt_rand( 100000000, 999999999 );

$str = $now->format('Y.m.d.H.i.s.u.z.v.U').$user.$pid.$rnd;

$id_session = hash('sha512', $str );

echo $id_session;

?>
```

Comment: Essa função hash('sha512', $str );
A partir da $str usando o algoritmo sha512 cria um hash, certo? Não importa a $str o hash sempre vai ter 512 bits?

Comment: @JulianoSilva Exatamente, independente do tamanho de `$str` a operação de *hash* `SHA256` dessa string sempre vai retornar uma string de `128 bytes` em representação hexadecimal.

Comment: O `mt_rand` é previsível!

Comment: @likeliz: Todo `PRNG` é previsível. O que muda, é a entropia de cada implementação, que é o que vai determinar se o gerador é criptograficamente seguro ou não. **Máquinas de estado finito são sempre previsíveis** e a única maneira de se ter um número verdadeiramente aleatório e imprevisível é por meio de de algum *hardware* capaz tirar proveito da incerteza quântica como os `TRNGs`

Comment: De fato para a maquina ela será previsível, mas isso é o ponto de vista. Se o gerador usado impede que o atacante preveja os dados futuros ou recupere os dados passados, podemos dizer que é "imprevisível". Um PRNG comum não está preocupado com a qualidade ou previsibilidade. O CSPRNG, por outro lado, eu digo que é imprevisível, porque também está preocupado com a força das operações para usadas fornecer bits bem distribuídos. Ignorando o "entropy-attack", o dispositivo já coleta entropia do uso de hardware (discos, rede, mouse...), que é aleatório, e processadores Intel tem o RDRAND.